# Is it possible to make straight line trajectory of a certain point on the unit circle rolling on the special curve?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, cycloid

I'm interested in cycloid and make another problem about it.
If a unit circle rolls one lap on the straight line, the point on the circle draws a cycloid trajectory. Then what if a unit circle rolls one lap on the special curve $l$ so that the corresponding trajectory is a straight (horizontal) line?

[image]

I don't even know if the curve really exists, but try to find the curve on these settings:

$l: x=f(s), y=g(s)$ where $s \in [0,2\pi]$ means 'rolling distance on $l$'
$C$: unit circle rolling on $l$ with its center point $c(s)$
$p(s)$: the point on $C$ which makes the horizontal line trajectory we want.

$p(s)=(p_1(s),p_2(s))$ can be expressed by defining three vectors:

$p(s)=q(s)+u(s)+v(s)$ .... (2)

where

$q(s)=(f(s), g(s))$ is the tangent point at which $l$ meets $C$,
$u(s)$ is the unit vector from $q(s)$ to $c(s)$, and
$v(s)$ is the unit vector from $c(s)$ to $p(s)$

and make parametric equations below:

$\int_{0}^{s}{\sqrt{f'(u)^2+g'(u)^2}}=s$ .... (1)
$p_2(s)=0$ .... (2)

Eqn(1) is from the curve length formula. If $C$ rolls distance $s$, the curve length behind becomes $s$.
Eqn(2) is from the condition where $p(s)$ is on the horizontal line.

Finding exact form of $u(s)$, $v(s)$ and simplifying them result in the system of 1st order nonlinear ODEs below:

$(f'(s))^2 + (g'(s))^2 = 1$
$-g(s)+\sin(s)g'(s)+(\cos(s)-1)f'(s)=0$

so terrible equations... even WolframAlpha doesn't solve it. I cannot go further.
Are there some well-known keywords about the initial problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "special curve" is a circle with twice the radius. This produces the [Tusi couple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tusi_couple).

[image]

Comment: OMG that's really simple and amazing..!! Thanks also for the keyword!!

Comment: @Parcly Taxel How do I derive an equation for the hypotrochoid so obtained?